# Why isn't iCheck checkbox value being passed using Ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax, icheck

I am using iCheck checkbox plugin on my site. I am trying to pass the checkbox checked/unchecked value from my html to a php file for database update using Ajax.
The problem is that the checkbox value isn't being sent over to my php file.

The html code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="mail_ssl" id="mail_ssl">
```

The Ajax code and initiation of the iCheck plugin

```
$(function(){

 $('#mail_ssl').iCheck({
checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue'
                }); 

$('#mail_ssl').on('ifChecked', function () { 

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
data: {mail_ssl : 'yes'},
url: 'mail_settings.php',
success: function(response) {
    alert(response);
        }
    });
  })  

}); // end function
```

And finally the code in the php file

```
$updSettings = "";
$mail_ssl = "";
$customer_id = 1;

$mail_ssl = $_POST['mail_ssl'];
$updSettings = $mail_ssl;

$UpdateMailSettings = "update class_customer_settings set smpt_ssl=" . 
$updSettings . " where customer_id =" .$customer_id;
mysql_query($UpdateMailSettings, $con);

mysql_close($con);
```

This is re-use of a code I wrote previously which I thought would work fine, but it's not. I am not able to see what's the matter this time around.
Any help would be great!

Comment: Do you check the checkbox manually or using another JS code?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used iCheck in awhile but this is some code I previously used from a project to test whether it was checked or unchecked, returning a boolean. (Replaced with your element ID) It may help you, there is probably a better way of doing it.

```
 var isCHK = $('#mail_ssl').iCheck('update')[0].checked;
 if(isCHK){
  // iCheck is checked
 }else{
  // iCheck not checked
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, answered my own question as a comment to your proposal, please see above

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? If you go to network is it actually sending to mail_settings.php? what is initiating the send? atm that code looks like it will run when the page is loaded and nothing else? I could be wrong.